# How to get yyyy/mm/dd date format from yy/mm/dd?

Tags: php

```
    $date = "2016-10-04";
    $date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
    $tomorrow = date('y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));

    echo $tomorrow;
```

Using above php code add one day to the given value. Finally it returns 16-10-05. But I need it with full year as 2016-10-05. How I get that?

Comment: Change y to Y in date() and why are you using str_replace() no need of that type conversion

Comment: @RakeshSojitra It works. Great

Comment: I strongly recommend changing to using the `DateTime` class, as shown by @masterFly below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, use 'Y' not 'y'

```
$date = "2016-10-04";
$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));

echo $tomorrow;
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/p8bFh)**

Answer (score 3):

For full year use 'Y' instead of 'y'

```
$date = "2016-10-04";
$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));

echo $tomorrow;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use 'Y-m-d' instead of 'y-m-d'

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for the full list of date format values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change 'y-m-d' to 'Y-m-d' in your date function.

```
Y - A four digit representation of a year
y - A two digit representation of a year
```

Ref link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp

Try below code:

```
$date = "2016-10-04";
$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));

echo $tomorrow;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always better to use the `DateTime`. The below should work!

```
$date = new DateTime("2016-10-04");
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
echo $date->add($interval)->format("Y-m-d");
```

Note: You can get rid of `$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);` which seems unnecessary to me.

You can read more on DateTime and DateInterval from the PHP manual.

Cheers!

Comment: You don't even need to use `DateInterval` on this one, as `$date->modify ('+1 day')` works perfectly. ;)

Comment: @ChristianF, Thanks for the comment! I haven't used `modify` before. And It works!! Even simpler! Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. :)